# Shifting ECG signal to get out in the range of 0 to 3.3 volts so that my Arduino could read the signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, dac, level-shifting

[image]

Can you tell me what kind of level shifter circuit I need to add to my circuit so that my Arduino can read the ECG signal? My Arduino has ADC of 0 to 3.3 volts, but as you can see, I need a 500mv volts shift to get into a pure positive signal.

Comment: Do you just want to shift it, or amplify it as well to get good SNR on the arduino ADC?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think there's a bit of arrhythmia going on here so I'd be more inclined to get a proper check of your heart function by a doctor.